# boost assertion 'result1 ==n && result2 == n' in tee.hpp

Tags: c++, boost

I am a newbie to use boost
When running the program，Assertion `result1 == n && result2 == n` failed

[**Source file address**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/iostreams/tee.hpp).

What is the problem？how can I solve the problem
thanks

Comment: Which program do you run? The link you gave is a source header file from the library, and is not supposed to run "from its own volition".

Comment: I want to know under what circumstances would get this error? thanks   the error come from this header file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

It means that writing to one of the legs of the `tee` stream has failed:

```
std::streamsize write(const char_type* s, std::streamsize n)
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((
        is_convertible<
            BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME iostreams::category_of<Device>::type, output
        >::value
    ));
    std::streamsize result1 = iostreams::write(dev_, s, n);
    std::streamsize result2 = iostreams::write(sink_, s, n);
    (void) result1; // Suppress 'unused variable' warning.
    (void) result2;
    assert(result1 == n && result2 == n);
    return n;
}
```

You can see that if both writes worked as expected, `result1` and `result2` should both match `n`.

If the stream implementation you're using specifically documents another postcondition it is not compatible with Boost Iostreams and you would have to wrap it in a stream class that "does what is required" to make it fulfill the expectations expressed in this `assert`.

Of course, it can be as simple as "ENOENT" (disk full) happening, or a network stream failing (e.g. because of peer disconnect)